# Topology for a DC-DC step up converter for a single AA battery with 50V 10mA output

Tags: design, dc-dc-converter, efficiency, low-voltage

I need to design a very compact step up DC-DC converter for the single AA battery (input voltage 0.7-1-5V) with an output of 50V 10mA. The load should drain in a typical case about 2mA, but in certain cases, the load could drain even up to 10mA. The goal is to achieve the most efficiency possible. What topology do you suggest to use for it? Maybe you have some design ideas.

Comment: Is there any time limit on how long the 10mA draw lasts, or on its duty cycle? If you can characterize that, it might be possible to design your boost converter for the average draw rather than the peak draw, and use a reservoir capacitor on the 50V bus to provide the peaks when needed.

Comment: It depends on the device type connected to the output. The most of them drain 2-4 mA. Some few devices can drain even up to 10mA. The boost converter should be designed and optimized for the normal consumption, but it should also be able to deliver 10mA in case of usage of some devices with the high drain. So there are no Peaks. The consumption itself is very constant.

Comment: OK, then let me ask this: For those high-draw loads, does it even make sense to have a battery life that will be only on the order of 2-3 hours?

Comment: Yes, the working time of 2-3 hours for high drain devices would be ok, because this devices are very rare. But the compatibility should be there. For a normal use case the working time of 5-6 hours would be very ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not going to be easy since it's hard to make semiconductor circuits that switch nicely at only 700 mV supply.  I'd probably use a boost converter chip that can make 3.3 V from the 700 mV, then run the control electronics off of that.  Now you can use widely available digital logic to create a nice clean on/off signal that drives the final power switching element in the boost supply that makes the 50 V.

Unfortunately you are still left with two inconvenient choices.  If you use a NFET as the switch in the power boost converter, it will require probably around 10 V to switch properly.  Look around, but I don't think you're going to find a "logic level" fet that can handle the 50 V you need.  The other option is a NPN transistor.  That can easily be switched from 3.3 V logic and withstand the 50 V, but to maybe 200 mV C-E drop will be a good fraction of the 700 mV input.  The efficiency will be quite poor, at least at low battery voltages.

I think the deciding factor is how important efficiency is.  If it is a high priority, then a more complicated drive circuit using a NFET will be necessary.  If run time isn't that important, then the NPN switch will be easier and simpler to drive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. The Efficiency is very important. Therefor I was thinking about usage of ATTiny43  which can operate with some external parts from the battery voltage up to 0.7V to control the switches. It generates internal Voltage of 3V and the drain is very low. Furthermore I can also use the ADC of this microcontroller to control the output voltage. Now the big question for me is which topology is even more efficient. I'm choosing between Boost converter, Flyback converter and Push-Pull converter. An Idea for the switch could be the SI6562. Anything wrong so far?

Comment: @Mikh: A plain old boost converter will be simpler, and should be able to be more efficient if you're careful.  The difficulty with a boost will be the high step up ratio.  You will have to figure this out carefully so that max output current at min input voltage is just possible.

Comment: If you are drawing 10mA at the 50V output, note that this would be over 700mA referred to the input (assuming 100% efficiency). You'll want to check what your battery internal impedence is - even if it's a few hundred miliohms that means your first stage will actually need to run off maybe ~0.5V at full load. You'll probably need a really carefully designed boost converter to take that up to logic-level. Note that many boost converter ICs capable of running off <1V have a seperate, higher startup voltage. Check out the LTC3539, for example.

Comment: 10mA at 50V is an absolute worst case scenario. The normal consumption will be at 2-4 mA. The high quality batteries like duracell procell can deliver even such big currents. So that is not a problem. Unfortunately a higher startup voltage is not acceptable. That's why I can't use any standard solutions like LTC3539. So I need a very good power MOSFET with a lowest possible Vgs threshold and lowest possible gate charge and capacitance to minimize switching losses. Another Idea is to use some cirquits or ICs designed to charge a photo flash.

Comment: @Mikh: If you still want it to work at 10 mA out, then it needs to work at 10 mA out.  The fact that it will typically only need to produce 2-4 mA is irrelevant.  You have to decide what your real spec is, then design to that.  The point about internal resistance of the battery at 1 A is a good one, especially considering that the battery is pretty empty by the time its open circuit voltage goes below 1 V.  I'd use bipolars to make a oscillator that makes the logic supply, so ultra-low FET threshold voltage doesn't enter into it.